# kdb+ How do I import only specific columns from a CSV file into a table

Tags: csv, kdb, q-lang

Example:
CSV file with 4 headers: a,b,c,d.
How do I only "pick" columns b & d for example, so I end up with a q table with two columns with the b & d headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For columns that you want to skip, use the space character in the "types" string. So to pick 'b' and 'd' columns:

```
q)\cat test.csv
"a,b,c,d"
"1,blah,3,4"
q)
q)(" S J";enlist csv) 0: `:test.csv
b    d
------
blah 4
```

Comment: Follow up question: I guess there is no way to actually use the name of the header to pick up the column? If I have 100s of columns and only wanted to use the actual header name as a string to pick up the given column. Unless I write up a sep function to parse the first header row and get the index of the desired column header.

Comment: Might not be the most efficient solution, but you could load all the data and then select the columns you need, e.g. `select b,d from ("****";enlist csv) 0: \`:test.csv`

Comment: Thank you . One last question. How do I import ALL the columns as  strings, without having to type each column type as  ("SSSSSS...") I want to onlu do something like ("all columns data type";enlist csv). Don't want to have to type each columns data type.

Comment: If you know how many columns are in the table (or count them beforehand), just use take `#`, e.g.
 `(4#"*";enlist csv) 0: \`:test.csv`. You should be wary of loading all strings as symbols though, unless they are repeating strings. See more [here](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/strings-symbols-enumeration#when-to-use)

Comment: thanks James yet again, thats what I was looking for